# Page works on local host but not firebase or netlifly

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Im having an issue when deploying my react app, ive used firebase hosting before with no problems. Im making a simple news app using react, the app works 100% fine when running it on  a local host. but when i try to use firebase or even netlifly i get the same error. The page instantly crashes on load and it returns a type error r undefined. Not sure what is causing it to crash only when using hosting but not on a local host.

```js
function App() {
  const [first, setFirst] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [userNews, setUserNews] = useState([]);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  function handleClick(e) {
    getNews();
    setShow(false);

    e.preventDefault();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function news() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey="
      );
      const newsData = await response.json();
      setFirst(newsData.articles);
    }
    news();
  }, []);

  async function getNews() {
    const answer = await fetch(
      "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=" +
        query +
        "&from=2022-03-01&sortBy=popularity&language=en&apiKey="
    );
    const data = await answer.json();
    setUserNews(data.articles);
    //console.log(data)
  }

  function createCard(first, n) {
    return (
      <Article
        key={n}
        title={first.title}
        author={first.author}
        time={first.publishedAt}
        content={first.description}
        link={first.url}
        photo={first.urlToImage}
      />
    );
  }

  function createUserCard(userNews, i) {
    return (
      <UserArticle
        key={i}
        title={userNews.title}
        author={userNews.author}
        time={userNews.publishedAt}
        content={userNews.description}
        link={userNews.url}
        photo={userNews.urlToImage}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <form onSubmit={handleClick} className="input">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search."
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>search.</button>
      </form>
      {show && <div className="container">{first.map(createCard)}</div>}

      <div className="container">{userNews.map(createUserCard)}</div>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where is `first` coming from?  If it is null or undefined it will throw an exception when calling the `map()` function.  Is `first` available before `show`?  I think just a little more code would help.

Comment: first is just the state i stored data from the api call in . const [first, setFirst] = useState([]) sorry i wasnt sure what code to include because im really not sure whats causing the page to crash, https://news-aff3f.firebaseapp.com/ here is the link to the page from firebase, it loads but instantly crashes.

Comment: Can you post the rest of this component?  Unless it's too big, but I'd really like to see how `show` is involved and the order of operations with the logic of this component you're rendering.

Comment: I meant you should update your question to have the full component.  Copy/paste your App.js component into your question. It's not too big if you remove the extra white space and any code that's not used in reproducing your problem.  Be sure to read this Stack overflow post about creating a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It was giving me a error when trying to post it but it seems to have worked now so the whole app js is in the post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure without seeing the error happen in real time, but it looks like it tries to access a property on something, but gets undefined.  `r` is likely an alias for whichever object that you named but was renamed by the webpacker minification of the code in production.

My guess is that your api call is receiving a bad result, but you aren't properly handling unexpected results from the api.  If the result of your api query is anything but the object you expect, then you won't receive an `articles` property to call, thus an error.
Consider using `trycatch` to cover yourself:

```
async function getNews(){
  try {
    const answer = await fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q='+ query +'&from=2022-03-01&sortBy=popularity&language=en&apiKey=')
    const data = await answer.json();
    setUserNews(data.articles)
  } catch(error) {
     console.log(error)
  }
}
```

This will protect you when getting a bad response from your fetch, and your page won't crash.

Being in a production environment, especially if the backend is managed by a 3rd party provider like firebase, can lead you into possible cors issues, and you may not be getting the same results you would on localhost.

Use the `trycatch` on both your `getNews` and `news` functions (or anywhere you make an external api call, it's just good practice), so you can see if you're getting an error from that api call.  Make use of console.log in your `catch` blocks with the `error` object.  This will reveal right away if you're having issue with the fetch request.  Otherwise the code looks fine, and there aren't any issues with it at face value.

Comment: so i tried try and catch on both like you suggested and now im getting a XHR GEThttps://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey= error that says 426 upgrade required, as well as the same type error r undefined, would this be from a cors error like you mentioned? ope i think i found it, dug a little deeper and found this message essage "Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost.". thanks for all your help i appreciate it.